# call variable from inside foreach loop to put inside array

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

What I'm trying to do is get my `$streamitem_imageuploaded` value so I can pass it into my `$json` array. Has this got anything to do with a nested loop? When I send my json data back currently, all I get is undefined variable `$streamitem_imageuploaded` with the below code.

```
if($checkphoto_id['photo_id']==0){
    $sqlhhh = "SELECT * FROM userphotos WHERE photo_name='".$checkphoto_id['photo_title']."' AND photo_ownerid='".$checkphoto_id['streamitem_creator']."' AND photo_datetime='".$checkphoto_id['streamitem_timestamp']."' ORDER BY photo_id ASC";
    $resulthhh = mysqli_query ($mysqli,$sqlhhh)or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); 
    $photo_num=mysqli_num_rows($resulthhh);
    $images = array();
    while ($rowhhh = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulthhh)) {
        $imageArray = array(
                            'data' => $rowhhh['photo_imagedata'],
                            'photo_streamitem_id' => $rowhhh['photo_streamitem_id'],
                            'id' => $rowhhh['photo_id']
                            );
        $images[] = $imageArray;
    }
    foreach ($images as  $image) {
        if($photo_num==1){
            $streamitem_imageuploaded='<a href="photo.php?pid='.$image['id'].'&streamitem_id='.$image['photo_streamitem_id'].'"><img class="stream_images" style="width:200px;height:200px;object-fit:cover;margin:2px;padding:2px;" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($image['data']) .'" /></a>';
        }else{
            $streamitem_imageuploaded[]='<a href="photo.php?pid='.$image['id'].'&streamitem_id='.$image['photo_streamitem_id'].'"><img class="stream_images" style="width:100px;height:100px;object-fit:cover;margin:2px;padding:2px;" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($image['data']) .'" /></a>';
        }
    }
}
```

Store the outputted value inside my $json array

```
$json = array(
    'posts' => array(),
    'count' => $rowcount,
    'commentlinktoggle' => $sendcommentlinktoggle,
    'streamitem_formholder' => $streamitem_formholder,
    'stopcommentsbutton' => $stopcommentsbutton,
    'streamitem_uploadimage_count' => $streamitem_uploadimage_count,
    'streamitem_imageuploaded' => $streamitem_imageuploaded,
);
```

**UPDATE**

Edit changed and still getting same result

```
if($photo_num==0){
    $streamitem_imageuploaded='';
}
if($photo_num==1){
    $streamitem_imageuploaded='<a href="photo.php?pid='.$image['id'].'&streamitem_id='.$image['photo_streamitem_id'].'"><img class="stream_images" style="width:200px;height:200px;object-fit:cover;margin:2px;padding:2px;" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($image['data']) .'" /></a>';
}
if($photo_num>1){
    $streamitem_imageuploaded[]='<a href="photo.php?pid='.$image['id'].'&streamitem_id='.$image['photo_streamitem_id'].'"><img class="stream_images" style="width:100px;height:100px;object-fit:cover;margin:2px;padding:2px;" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($image['data']) .'" /></a>';
}
```

This code works in a standard php page no issues. just not when trying to call the variable from inside an array.

Comment: Is `$streamitem_imageuploaded` supposed to be an array or string? You use it both ways in the `foreach`.

Comment: If `$images` is empty, then `$streamitem_imageuploaded` is never set. Also, what line is the error referencing and what line is that in this code?

Comment: I get a value back for the  var $streamitem_imageuploaded. As said above, you use the var inconsistently. In one block as string and in another as array. Regardless, both should work if the rest of your script give back the values.

I'd recommed to check:
1. $checkphoto_id['photo_id']==0 (is it really 0)
2. $photo_num
3. Check contents of $images.
Test rest of execution by taking while loop away and keeping the image array and setting $photo_num = 1;

Comment: It's suppose to be a json string.. but if there is more than one image it outputs them in an array. 

The line error is `'streamitem_imageuploaded' => $streamitem_imageuploaded,`` inside the $json array. I'm certain its because the variable is inside the foreach loop it can't find it.

Comment: I removed the array  `[] ` off of `$streamitem_imageuploaded `and still get the same error.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn see my update. I tried what you suggested and still getting the same response of Undefined variable.

Comment: @Barmar the first one is a string because its one single image. The second is an array because the user may have uploaded more than one image.

Comment: Don't do that. It makes processing the response more complicated, since the caller has to deal with getting either an array or a string. Just use an array consistently -- if there's just one image, it will be an array with a single element.

Comment: @Barmar That's fine. But as you can see by the image style how would I style differently between a single image and multiple images? This is the only reason I did this

Comment: Maybe the problem is variable scope. Are you assigning to `$json` in the same function that contains the loop?

Comment: Nope. its separate because the variable value doesnt come from the database $row within the loop..But a separate one..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All i needed to do was to add an array outside the foreach loop and then call this within my $json array

```
    $streamitem_imageuploaded = array();
```

I used this when researching for my answer. 
[Return all values stored in var outside foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769110/return-all-values-stored-in-var-outside-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Added some static values to simulate things. This works fine without generating undefined for your $streamitem_imageuploaded var. So problem must be in your mysql code or your other conditionals.

```
$rowhhh =1;
$photo_num = 1;
$images = array();
  if ($rowhhh == 1) {
    $imageArray = array(
                        'data' => $rowhhh['photo_imagedata'],
                        'photo_streamitem_id' => $rowhhh['photo_streamitem_id'],
                        'id' => $rowhhh['photo_id']
                        );
    $images[] = $imageArray;
}
foreach ($images as  $image) {
    if($photo_num==1){
        $streamitem_imageuploaded='<a href="photo.php?pid='.$image['id'].'&streamitem_id='.$image['photo_streamitem_id'].'"><img class="stream_images" style="width:200px;height:200px;object-fit:cover;margin:2px;padding:2px;" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($image['data']) .'" /></a>';
    }else{
        $streamitem_imageuploaded[]='<a href="photo.php?pid='.$image['id'].'&streamitem_id='.$image['photo_streamitem_id'].'"><img class="stream_images" style="width:100px;height:100px;object-fit:cover;margin:2px;padding:2px;" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($image['data']) .'" /></a>';
    }
}
$json = array(
'posts' => array(),
'count' => $rowcount,
'commentlinktoggle' => $sendcommentlinktoggle,
'streamitem_formholder' => $streamitem_formholder,
'stopcommentsbutton' => $stopcommentsbutton,
'streamitem_uploadimage_count' => $streamitem_uploadimage_count,
'streamitem_imageuploaded' => $streamitem_imageuploaded,
);
print_r($json);
```

Comment: when I remove if($checkphoto_id['photo_id']==0){ from my original code and add yours  it works.

Comment: So the issue is with the conditions... Probably an idea to check why your $checkphoto_id['photo_id']==0 does not evaluate to true. If you benefited from the answer, please be so kind to accept it.